# map insert(const_iterator hint, value) usage

Tags: c++

I am looking through *[cppreference map insert operation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert)* and find a usage:

```
iterator insert( const_iterator hint, const value_type& value ); //(since C++11)
```

> hint: iterator to the position before which the new element will be
>   inserted  (since C++11)

I know `map` and `set` are internally sorted, so how the usage "insert just after hint" could work?

Test code:

```
#include <set>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    set<int> foo = { 9,2,4,8,0 }; //0,2,4,8,9
    //foo.insert(-1); //-1,0,2,4,8,9

    const auto pos = foo.find(4);
    foo.insert(pos, -1); //I expected to get 0,2,4,-1,8,9
                        //(unreasonable since map should be always sorted but that's how I understand the function usage)
                       // And I got -1,0,2,4,8,9  same result as insert(value)

}
```

How does `insert(const_iterator hint, value)` work?

Comment: It works exactly as described. Inserting a new value into a map requires the new value's position to be determined. Without a hint, how the implementation does it is, by definition, implementation defined. Typically insertion starts at the root, and traverses the tree until the insertion spot is determined. A hint starts the tree traversal at the indicated value in the map.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik So roughly speaking, providing a hint could probably save some time during insertion?

Comment: @Rick Yes, With a hint at the right place, you can have constant time insertion (O(1)). But with a hint at the wrong place, you will have logarithmic time insertion (O(log n)), just like a regular insertion (but maybe with a worst constant)

Comment: Sure about that internal set sorting? As `std::set` by default uses `std::less<Key>`, I'd expect `0,2,4,8,9` instead of `0,2,4,9,8`...

Comment: @JHBonarius thanks. I've corrected it.

Answer (score 2):

The iterator you pass is "just" a hint, meaning the function will fallback on regular insertion if the hint is wrong.

If the hint is right, insertion will happen in amortized constant time, but if it is wrong, it will be logarithmic in the size of the map or set.

To see how it is done in llvm stdlib : https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/master/include/map